# Use runas with a domain account on a non-domain machine in Windows 2k/XP/Vista/7

Tags: windows, domain, runas

My Windows 7 computer is on LAN in an intranet with a Windows domain, but it is not a member of that domain. However, I need to run some applications under domain accounts while I'm logged on locally as a local admin.

I know you can use the `runas` utility to start processes under accounts different from the one under which you have logged on. The thing is that Windows needs to know or authenticate the account under which a process is starting.

When I do something like:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME cmd.exe
```

(and put in a correct password afterwards) I get this kind of error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd.exe
1326: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Does anybody know how to cope with this?

Answer (score 46):

The `runas` command has an extra option `/netonly` that allows running local apps as a domain user, on a non-domain machine. It worked for me when I ran on Windows 7 Professional - but it does require an elevated Command Prompt.

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\user command
```

More details at the below site:

> http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/10/12/tip-how-to-run-programs-as-a-domain-user-from-a-non-domain-computer/

Comment: The addition of `/netonly` worked for me where my machine is on *a* domain, but a different domain from that of the user I needed to impersonate.

Comment: This worked for me, although I didn't think it was going to, as it still had the logged-in user name in the connection window greyed out. But after connecting I run the query "select SYSTEM_USER" and it was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you're trying to use domain credentials to log onto a machine that is not a member of that domain.  This can't be done.  Domain accounts only log onto domain computers.  Local accounts only log onto the local machine (with exceptions).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comprehensive and clear answer. However, this sounds strange to me: My machine is not on the domain. However: If I want to use the domain's resources, such as shared folders/printers I simple issue net use \\server\resource /user:domain\domainuser and provide my domain password and I can get to them. Why can I not use runas likewise?

Comment: When you join a machine to the domain, it's creating a higher level of trust between machine & domain vs. shared resources.  Allowing a user to connect to a printer or file share is a lot safer (from an admin perspective) than joining an unknown machine to the domain.  The short answer is that it's all for security.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Put another way, For the shared remote items, the non-domain computer isn't trusting the domain.  It is just passing the credentials through to gain access to remote resources.  Permitting a user to run programs is an entirely different thing, particularly when (since it doesn't know anything about / trust the domain) the non-domain computer doesn't even know for sure the user exists, let alone that it should be allowed to run programs.

Comment: Kara - I think you misunderstood the question. He's asking how to log on to a computer that is part of a domain with credentials for that domain, but *from* a computer that is not joined to the domain. Runas is the answer he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Runas in my AD envrionment as this:

> runas /env /profile /user:domain\useraccnt cmd

Give it a try, it always work for me!

Comment: Thanks, r0ca. The thing is that my computer is not on the domain I use in the command "runas". It is no domain at all, actually.

I used another advice from here: http://serverfault.com/questions/88208/mimic-the-behavior-of-a-machine-added-to-a-domain

ksetup /setrealm YOURDOMAIN.TLD 
ksetup /addkdc YOURDOMAIN.TLD yourkdc.yourdomain.tld 
ksetup /setmachpassword the-password-from-above 
ksetup /mapuser yourdomainaccount@YOURDOMAIN.TLD yourlocalaccount 

Now, I get this:
1787: The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

Comment: You won't be able to perform this operation as long as the computer is not listed in the domain. You should RDP on a PC then ;)

Comment: But +1 for the line above, interresting!